# Error starting React app from different machine

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

After moving a project from different machine by external memory source to my current machine, I and ran
     npm install
on the command line
the response I received looked like this

```
Macintosh:pokedex TimLowe$ npm install

> fsevents@1.1.3 install /Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/gitHub/homeworks/react-pokeapp-homework/pokedex/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.3 and node@10.0.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

action_after_build.target.mk:6: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:225:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.11.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/gitHub/homeworks/react-pokeapp-homework/pokedex/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/gitHub/homeworks/react-pokeapp-homework/pokedex/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/gitHub/homeworks/react-pokeapp-homework/pokedex/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.11.1/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/gitHub/homeworks/react-pokeapp-homework/pokedex/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/gitHub/homeworks/react-pokeapp-homework/pokedex/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/gitHub/homeworks/react-pokeapp-homework/pokedex/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:947:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:236:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.11.1/bin/node" "/Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/gitHub/homeworks/react-pokeapp-homework/pokedex/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/gitHub/homeworks/react-pokeapp-homework/pokedex/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.11.1/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/gitHub/homeworks/react-pokeapp-homework/pokedex/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/TimLowe/Desktop/CodeBridge:WDI/gitHub/homeworks/react-pokeapp-homework/pokedex/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

up to date in 97.145s
Macintosh:pokedex TimLowe$
```

Comment: Gah! That image is painful to look at! Is there any way you could paste the text of the error message into your question in a code block?

Comment: Well, the error is: xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance.I think you don't have the required dependecy.

Comment: @TheodorB what dependency? 
Xcode?
if so it looks like I cannot download the most recent version of Xcode to my machine.
OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6

Answer (score 0):

`xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance`

This is error occurs after moving a project from a different machine by external memory source to my current machine and running npm install

When attempting to install Xcode to my machine I receive an error that I cannot install Xcode.

Does anyone know any way around this?